# Issue sending attachment using PHP

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I try to send an automatic created e-mail on my website using PHP. After some effort, I ended up with this script, but for some reason I get an error and I can't figure out why.

```
function sendMail($_POST) {
    $fileatt = "http://www.mysite.com/contract.pdf";  
    $fileatt_type = "application/pdf"; 
    $fileatt_name = "contract.pdf"; 

    $email_from = "info@mysite.com"; 
    $email_subject = "Your Contract";  
    $email_message = "Thanks for your booking! Here is your contract"; 

    $email_to = $_POST['mail']; // Who the email is to

    $headers = "From: ".$email_from;

    $file = fopen($fileatt,'r'); 
    $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt)); 
    fclose($file);

    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
    $email_message .= "\n\n";

    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" . 
    " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
    //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
    //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
    $data .= "\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

    $ok = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    if($ok) { 
        echo "You file has been sent to the email address you specified";
    } else { 
        die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. Please go back and try again!"); 
    }
}
```

And the script does send the email and includes the attachement BUT the attachment has a 0kb size. This makes sense if I see my error:

```
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://www.mysite.com/test.pdf in /customers/9/7/5/mysite.com/functions.php on line 712
Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 in /customers/9/7/5/mysite.com/functions.php on line 712
```

Could someone provide me some more information on how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to the over size of the file you tried to upload. Increse 'Max_upload_filesize' in your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use a script like PHPMailer or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.com/). This is what most people do and takes the difficulty away from emailing with PHP. Trying to use the `mail()` function in PHP without being an expert is a killer!

Answer (score 0):

What size is the attachment you've tried? Maybe you should increase the upload file size limit, see http://drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: I doubt the size is the problem... It's only 13KB